# How to change BackColor of Button inside a UserControl from another UserControl?

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I am using an asp button inside a user control and this user control is in another user control, I want to change the back color of the asp button from second user control,

I have used the below code but the color doesn't change. When I change the button's text using `btn.Text` this will change, but when I change `btn.BackColor` this is not working.

```
Dim btn As Button = DirectCast(ucontrolLetterSelect.FindControl(buttonID), System.Web.UI.WebControls.Button)
btn.BackColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red
```

Comment: Don't use `FindControl`, you are creating hidden dependencies between the page, the usercontrol and the child-usercontrol. Hidden because the ID is evaluated at runtime. This will fail if somebody changes the ID or the type of the control, in future. Instead provide public properties that can be set from the controller(the page or the parent UserControl). Use a meaningful name for the property like `Public Property DeleteColor As Color`. Then the property changes the color of the control.

Comment: when I change the button's text using btn.Text this will change, but when I change btn.BackColor this is not working.

Comment: I don't know Web.UI.WebControls enough to give an answer, but are you sure BackColor works "as is" (have you tried changing the backcolor directly?) Most UI frameworks require to set a button "flat" to allow you to change the backcolor directly. Don't know if that's possible in standard web ui controls without CSS.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create an exposed public property on the user control who's button that you want to change.  Then you could set this property through the parent user control.

Exmaple :

I have a user control called TestControl1.ascx

I placed a button called btnTest on this user control

I also created a public property called SetUserControlButtonBackColor in the codebehind of this user control.

```
Public Property SetUserControlButtonBackColor As Color
    Get
        Return mColor
    End Get
    Set(value As Color)
        Me.btnTest.BackColor = value
    End Set
End Property
```

I place this user control into my webpage and put a button on my webpage called Button1

On the click event of Button1 I set the public exposed property of my user control which sets the back color of the button within the user control.

```
Protected Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
    Me.TestControl1.SetUserControlButtonBackColor = Drawing.Color.Aqua
End Sub
```

Now when you click the button on your web page it will change the color of your user control